# Django Inline formset for editing multiple related records at once - the right way to go?

Tags: django, django-forms, inline-formset

When using inline formsets, how does one do paging? I'm using django 1.1. 
The situation I'm in, is that the user needs to be able to edit the related objects quickly and easily (which is why I think I should be using an inline formset). However, there can be a more than a hundred objects to edit, which makes a pretty large formset, so paging would make sense.

Is there a better way to be doing this?

Thanks
Bert

Comment: Looks like you are trying to push the limits of what the admin interface is supposed to do. I suggest rolling your own interface... Inlines do not have paging capabilities; you will end up with a really long page, not very user-friendly.

Comment: Thanks, but its not for the admin interface. Should I rather be using regular formsets for editing the related objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I couldn't get paging to work with formsets.

Instead I extended BaseInlineFormSet and changed the get_queryset method to return only a subset of the objects that were needed to be edited and set a limit on the maximum number of objects returned. So when the user wants to edit related objects, they can only edit a set number of objects at a time e.g. 20 of the possible 60.When the user has completed editing the first 20, and submits the form, the next 20 will be displayed.