# Django ModelChoiceField and performance with >100 formset forms

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a `CustomerForm` in Django that contains a formset with a list of `Meter`s.  Customers have meters and meters are located at facilities owned by customers.  The form allows users to assign meters to one of the customer's facilities.

The `Meter` model has a field:

```
facility = models.ForeignKey(
    Facility, 
    blank=True, 
    null=True, 
    default=None, 
    related_name='meters',
)
```

The formset is generated via:

```
meters_formset_class = inlineformset_factory(
    Customer,
    Meter,
    extra=0,
    form=MeterInlineForm
)
```

and uses the following `MeterInlineForm' definition:

```
class MeterInlineForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = (
            'facility',
        )
        model = Meter

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MeterInlineForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        meter = kwargs.get('instance', None)

        if meter != None:
            if meter.customer != None:
                self.fields['facility'].queryset = \
                    meter.customer.facilities.order_by('name')
```

This works great -- until I have a customer with hundreds of meters.  Then, as noted in the Django docs, A `ModelChoiceField`:

> Allows the selection of a single model object, suitable for
>   representing a foreign key. Note that the default widget for
>   ModelChoiceField becomes impractical when the number of entries
>   increases. You should avoid using it for more than 100 items.

***Question***: How should I fix this performance problem?

***Update***: This boils down on how to handle large UpdateViews in general.  For DetailViews I work some AJAXy magic to only get data for the records that are visible to the user.  This doesn't work for UpdateViews because the user might update record 1 and record 300 -- which are probably not visible at the same time.

***Update***: Here is an example of part of the meter formset table:

[image]

***Update***: Another user's approach to the problem: [Django Inline formset for editing multiple related records at once - the right way to go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503236/django-inline-formset-for-editing-multiple-related-records-at-once-the-right-w)

Comment: Are you after something along the lines of `raw_id_fields` in the admin?

Comment: I don't think so.  Ultimately, I'd like to have other inputs beyond the FK field as well.  So what I really need is a way to "chunk" up the formset data for display.